# Ionic header title not vertically align middle for some android devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, vertical-alignment, title

I'm working on an app with ionic framework and cordova. But now I met an issue. The header title cannot be aligned vertically middle.

**Screen shot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
    <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="logout()">
      <i class="icon ion-log-out">Logout</i>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

```
ion-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 90px 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Juste add this to your CSS

Comment: Thank you for your answer. unfortunately, it didn't work.